# Can we ship a small webapp with IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis, iis-express

**Is there a way to ship a small webapp in MVC2 with IIS Express**, so there will no need for installing it on IIS, what's the version, ohh I don't have cause I want to run this on Windows Vista Home, etc etc ...

Kind'a having a small exe and run the WebApp on the IIS Express, for those who prefer the web environment rather than a windows environment to work, and off course, been a webapp, it should be able to be access it from any computer on the ethernet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the IIS blog:

> ### Distributing IIS Express
>
> The official release allows you to
>   distribute the IIS Express MSIs as-is.
>   Since this is enabled by the licensing
>   agreement, you don’t need special
>   approval.
>
> Note that you can’t distribute the IIS
>   Express official release in any other
>   way. For example, you can’t copy a
>   subset of the binaries that are
>   included in the MSI and ship them as
>   part of your product. Please review
>   the IIS 7.5 Express EULA before you
>   distribute IIS Express.

Source: http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2011/01/17/iis-7-5-express-official-release-highlights.aspx